# Connecting to FUSEKI from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sparql, fuseki

I am trying to send SPARQL queries that I create in JavaScript to FUSEKI.
I am quite a n00b and am not really sure if 1. this is possible, and 2. if it is, how to do it.

I am trying via XMLHttpRequest(), but I think the way the query is formatted may be wrong? I'm just pretty lost right now and hope someone can help or give me examples of how to send my queries.

So far I've mainly been getting these error like:

"INFO  [145] 400 SPARQL Update: No 'update=' parameter (1 ms)"
"INFO  [140] 415 Must be application/sparql-update or application/x-www-form-urlencoded (got text/plain)"

Here is an example of code I have been trying:

```
var testQuery = 'SELECT * WHERE{?timer <http://schema.org/title>  ?title}';

var url = "http://localhost:3030/ds/query";
// var url = "http://localhost:3030/ds/update";
var params = "testQuery";
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.open("POST", url+"?"+params, true);
http.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send();
```

Comment: Why don't you use HTTP `GET`?

Comment: The query request is being sent to the update endpoint.

Comment: AndyS is right, that was also my second thought, although the code here shows a different URL. Are you sure that the code corresponds to the error message that you get?

Answer (score 0):

You should have `url + '?query=' + encodeURIComponent(testQuery)` as the second parameter when calling the `open()` function.